# Having trouble getting a Switch-Case statement to work in C <stdio.h>

Tags: c, stdio, switch-statement

can anyone tell me why i can't get this menu to let me make a selection? It skips from letting me make an option right to "Wrong Selection". Thanks in advance for the help, i'll make sure to thank you personally.

```
printf("Welcome to the Inventroy Control System");
printf("\nPlease make a selection");
printf("\n\n\ta) Display Inventory");

printf("\n\tb) Add New Items");
printf("\n\tg) Exit");
printf("\nSelect what you would like to do");
printf("\nOption Chosen: ");

fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c", &input);

input = toupper(input);

switch(input)

{

case 'A':
{
    funa(j,a);
    break;
}
case 'B':
{
    j = funb(amount,a);
    break;
}
case 'G':
{
    fung();
    break;
}
default:
{
    printf("\nWrong Selection");
}
}
```

Comment: What input are you giving it (exactly...include when/if you press return), and what output (or lack there of) are you getting.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely you're reading an `\n` because [**`fflush(stdin);` is wrong**](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html).

Instead try:

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
       ^
```

There are numerous C FAQ entries about this, here's one that explains [how to flush stdin](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html).

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot for the help, i did as suggested and it worked! Also thanks for the link on the flush. Great Help!